# Installing a nat network interface on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have tried using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778392/install-second-network-interface-on-virtualized-ubuntu-server) exactly to add eth1 as a nat network interface but my machine still fails to connect to the internet. What may still prevent my machine from connecting?

My configuration files:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Ubuntu 17.04 cannot connect to the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950470/virtualbox-ubuntu-17-04-cannot-connect-to-the-internet)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950470/virtualbox-ubuntu-17-04-cannot-connect-to-the-internet), running

```
dhclient eth1 -v
```

works to connect to the internet, but prevents connections on the other 
adapter. Restarting reverts to the previous scenario